# Android: GoogleMap v2 in a fragment requires the additional permissions

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to use GoogleMaps V2 within a fragment, but without success. In the emulator, I get the info, that I should update the play services. The same on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus. Once I updated the play services, I get the following error. All those permission - listed in the error - are part of my manifest file. Any idea?

**Remark:** I uploaded the [demo project to Github](https://github.com/Nagilo1/MyMap). Feel free to use it. I'm using IntelliJ but the GoogleMap API is from a former Eclipse project.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.demo.mymap/com.demo.mymap.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class fragment ... Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment ... Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional
>   following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a
>   correct behavior:

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.mymap" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyA6mS6BJy89Sgkj1GCgRrusQ84p_T5hLEA" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `<uses-permission>` elements to be children of `<manifest>`, not children of `<application>`.

Comment: Oh man, I feel ashamed. What an easy error. Thanks for the hint. Works fine. I'll accept your answer in some minutes.

Comment: @Matthias: You are not the only one who has been caught by this. I filed [an enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=128423) a while ago to get Lint to point out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on what the Logcat says:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the
>   additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml
>   to ensure a correct behavior:

Your permissions at your `Manifest` are declared wrong.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.mymap" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyA6mS6BJy89Sgkj1GCgRrusQ84p_T5hLEA" />

    </application>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your perrmissions must be defined outside the application definition, and must be children of `<manifest>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.mymap" >


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyA6mS6BJy89Sgkj1GCgRrusQ84p_T5hLEA" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

check the sample and the info of the official documentation:

**[AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html)**